# Select entries where only a Foreign Key is present for that ID

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have 4 SQL tables as follows.

- Registration
- Optional table 1 *[RegistrationID Foreign Key]*
- Optional table 2 *[RegistrationID Foreign Key]*
- Optional table 3 *[RegistrationID Foreign Key]*

Basically, Registration contains data for ALL those optional tables, but each optional table holds different additional data for that registration, via a foreign key.

Using LINQ to SQL, what's the best way to only select the registrations associated with that Option table?

**Pseudo-code would be**
*select all registrations where an entry in table [x] exists*

Appreciate your help
Marko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var results = from r in dc.Registration
              join o1 in dc.Optional1 on r.RegistrationID equals o1.RegistrationID
              select r;
```

This will only return the records in table Registration if they have associated records in Optional table 1